# Mongoid, Can not find models by geospatial calculation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have my model `A` with following fields:

```
field :location, type: Array

index( { location: '2d' }, { min: -180, max: 180 })

# Check if location is float
before_save :fix_location, if: :location_changed?
def fix_location
  self.location = self.location.map(&:to_f)
end
```

Then I have run indexing rake task.

Now I have model with cooridnates `[-4.430577206803733, 100.27785445050375]`

I want to query this model by its coordinates, I use same coordinates of my model:

```
loc = [-4.430577206803733, 100.27785445050375]
distance = 50 #km

models = A.where(location: {"$near" => loc, "$maxDistance" => distance.fdiv(111.12)})
```

When I run this code, It does return nothing. I change value of `loc` that is near to my coordinates and it still gives nothing.

What did I miss?

==== Update ====

I have changed my code to this:

```
models = A.where(location: {"$near" => {lng: 100.27785445050375, lat: -4.430577206803733}, "$maxDistance" => distance.fdiv(111.12)})
```

Still gives me an empty array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution. I just simply forgot to run indexing rake task.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing location coordinates in Latitude, Longitude format. MongoDB expects Longitude first.

Comment: How to make mongoDB get Latitude first?